# Is there a function to format datetime.date() object in dataframe to single quoted string to match the following regex?

Tags: pandas

Problem Statement: Out of all available records which day has the highest difference between maximum_pressure and minimum_pressure

- assign the date in string format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Make sure you enclose it with single quote

I am getting error:

```
re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

E   IndexError: list index out of range

(out is the variable from where my program is read as file)

Data Frame in data.csv has Day column of string type "01/03/2009...." like this.

Attempt 1:

1. df5=data
2. df5['Day']=pd.to_datetime(df5['Day'], format='yyyy-mm-dd')
3. pmax=df5.iloc[:,-6]
4. pmin=df5.iloc[:,-5]
5. df5['PressureDiff']=pmax-pmin
6. pm=df5["PressureDiff"].max()
7. df6=df5[df5["PressureDiff"]==pm]
8. from datetime import datetime
9. max_p_range_day = datetime.strftime(df6.values[0][0],"'%Y-%m-%d'") # single quotes within double quotes

Attempt 2:
Changing from line 8

df61=df6.values[0][0]

max_p_range_day = df61.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Output 1: '2018-03-23'
Output 2: 2018-03-23

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean `df5['Day'].dt.strftime("max_p_range_day = '%Y-%m-%d'")`?

Comment: the regex will check if I have correctly converted date to expected string format within quotes and assigned it to max_p_range_day. Its going to read my code as file from 'out' variable.